Place child elements of div exactly the same positions
I have an image of a town containing some buildings and I placed it as a background of a div.
Now I wanted to add inside that div smaller images with each building from the background so they would be exactly at the same positions as on the background image.
The smaller images are slightly lighter than original buildings on the background so I will later get the hover effect with highlighted building.
The problem is that my buildings are flying around on different devices. No matter if I set the left/top with percentages % or vh, px. They always change the positions relatively to the main div with town view background.
What I need is the background and smaller images inside stay always the same no matter what.
I am using only simple css with some tailwind css styles but no matter what i do it does not work. It would be nice if the picture wouldn't be scrollable so people on all devices see the full picture.
What is the best way to do that?
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url('/images/Town_5.png'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <img src="/images/House_4.png" class="relative" style="left:7%; top:5%; width:17%">
    <img src="/images/Mine_1.png" class="relative" style="left:40%; top:0%; width:21%">
</div>


Position in terms of % left and top relative to the original picture.

Can you please fix image links in your code, and provide some visual presentation or just use code snippet that we can run your code.

@ilyasbilgihan Lets say this is an example of what i am doing, i always need blue house in Asia and red house in Europe. Always in exactly the same place: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=R3CFb3O3Ox

Don't use a background image... use an actual image and overlay the other images on top. BG images don't scale the same was as inline images. Something like - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYELEo

If you use percentage, then do the same for background-size :) It should then match even if the image gets distorted. IF You also give a width (without height)and an aspect-ratio to the container, the background image & image won't get distorted ...

The main problem is that you need to define each buildings width as a percentage of width of the container. For example width of mine is 20% of the whole width, so we use 20vw. Then just position them.


*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.background {
  width: 100vw; 
  aspect-ratio: 1024 / 768;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.mine {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: 0%;
  left: 40%;
}
.house {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18vw;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: 6%;
  left: 7%;
}
.mine:hover, .house:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #4444dd);
}
<div class="background">
    <div class="mine"></div>
    <div class="house"></div>
</div>



